# URIs, URLs and URNs

Tags: rest, url, networking, uri, netsuite

Could someone help me with the below.

I am a bit of confused regarding URI and URLs. I read somewhere that all URLs are URIs. Now I have the following URL:

https://forms.eu2.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=xx&deploy=1&compid=xxxxxx&h=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Could someone tell me if this URL is a URI as well? If not, how can i convert it to URI.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: all urls are uris... so yes it is. uri = uniform resource identifier, that is, the name is unique in a given scope, but there is not necessary a resource at that "adress" (it could even be something else than an address). url = ur locator, that is, something exists at that place.

Comment: That means that if a rest client needs URI I can use this URL instead without changing it?

Comment: a rest client should need an url. a valid uri can be that: ```mydomain.com/nothing-live-here``` without protocol. good luck at invoking this. but there is quite often a confusion between both, people tend to call an uri what is really an url, and vice versa